# I am trying to make a for loop but my computer is returning the following:Cannot read property 'length' of null

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my for loop:

```
    function ubbify(){
    var inputTextStr = document.getElementById("mytext".value);
        // write the logic for ubbify
        //document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = inputTextStr;
        for (var i = 0; i < inputTextStr.length(); i++) {
            console.log("Character: " + inputTextStr[i]);
            document.write(inputTextStr[i]);
            console.log(i);}
```

Here is my HTML:

```
    <form>
        Enter text here:
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="my-text">
        <button type="button" onclick="ubbify('my-
    text'.toString().value)">Submit</button>
```

I am trying to make a string, not an array. On the console it returns: Cannot return property 'length' of null. I am not sure what that means. Please Help!

Comment: The function:  document.getElementById(), like the name suggests looks up the element by its ID, in the HTML DOM.
In the HTML code that you have provided, there is no element with the id: 'mytext'.

Perhaps you intend to use:
<input type="text" name="my-text" id="mytext">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the property outside of the method (and use `my-test` as string):

```
var inputTextStr = document.getElementById("my-text").value;
//                                                 ^
```

Beside the wring using of the lenght property, i suggest to usse the if in the call of the `ubbify` function, becuase that allows to use it inside of the functio for further processing. The input need an `id` attribute.

```js
function ubbify(id) {
    var inputTextStr = document.getElementById(id).value;
    for (var i = 0; i < inputTextStr.length; i++) {
        console.log("Character: " + inputTextStr[i]);
    }
}
```

```html
<form>
    Enter text here: <br>
    <input type="text" id="my-text"> <button type="button" onclick="ubbify('my-text')">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: inputTextStr.length() will also fail as length is a property, not a method.

Answer (score 3):

It's because document.getElementById("mytext".value) returns null, which is because there is no element in the DOM with ID equal to "mytext".value.

I think you want

```
var inputTextStr = document.getElementById("my-text").value;
```